# Bootstrap modal not working in safari / windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

This Bootstrap modal is not working in Safari but there is no issues in Chrome and Firefox.

I also have a javascript select. When I remove the javascript select  the popup works in Safari but otherwise its not working.

```
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="fav-popup">
  <div class="modal-dialog">         
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header modal-fav-header">
           <h2 class="txt-pop-head">Add category</h2>
           <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="fa fa-close"></span></button>       
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                     <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-control" placeholder="">  
                    </div>
                </div> 

                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="select-box select-gray">
                         <label>Category</label>
                         <select class="form-control input-control wide custom">
                           <option value="">Product Category</option>
                         </select>
                       </div>
                    </div> 
               </div>  
               <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                   <div class="btn-group-custom">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-draft" value="Cancel">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-next" value="Create">  
                   </div>
               </div>    

        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">  
         <h2 class="txt-profile-head">Add Category</h2>

               <div class="row">  
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                     <div class="row-adj">
                        <div class="products-block">
                          <div class="category" style="background:#fff;">
                               <a href="#fav-popup" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fav-popup"><button type="button" class="btn">+</button>
                               <h3>Create a Category</h3>
                               </a>
                          </div>
                        </div> 
                      </div>  
                  </div> 


</div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var bodyTag = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
bodyTag.className = bodyTag.className.replace("noJS", "hasJS");
</script>
<script src="js/SelectBox.js"></script>
<script>    
      $(function() {
          $("select.custom").each(function() {                  
              var sb = new SelectBox({
                  selectbox: $(this),
                  height: 150,
                  width: 200,
              });
          });

      });
</script>
```

Comment: You mean safari 5.1.7 for windows?

Comment: yes, safari 5.1.7

Comment: You know it is far outdated (and never been stable)? Much more people using IE6  than this version of safari, developing web apps for such old and unstable browser is pointless IMO.